# Chat bot for traders

Tags: fixed-income, trading, python, bloomberg, reuters

In the framework of my internship at a bank, I want to write a chat bot program in Python that allows our bond traders via their Bloomberg terminal chat box application to type in structured command lines such as "[name] [isin] [date]" that the chat bot will interpret as a query to the API of another financial information platform (Reuters) and in return the chat bot  will output the information such as latest price, axes and yield etc. in the Bloomberg chat box.

My question is, given my limited knowledge in API and data ( I have an economics/finance background), I would gladly have some tips or pointers as to how to tackle this project. Also, is it even possible to make use of Bloomberg chat box and retrieve data from elsewhere on there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: im voting to close becuase this is a coding question. But essentially I suspect the answer to your question is NO. Unless bloomberg chat has a trigger text input to invoke some external script (which I strong suspect it does not) then I doubt you will be a) permitted, or b) actually able to actively monitor the chat text to watch for text triggers to execute your code and then return it to the chatbox. I dont know the answer but it sounds completely unfeasible

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because should be on coding site

Comment: It's probably more suited to SO but quite broad so not migrating.